# How to use FileSystemWatcher with FIFO processing in C#

Tags: c#, windows, filesystemwatcher

How to use the `FileSystemWatcher` with FIFO processing? The `FileSystemWatcher` trigger event whenever the files are pasted in the directory, so I want to perform one file at a time as first in first out processing. How is this possible and how to implement it? Kindly provide with an example.

I want to watch over the directory using `FileSystemWatcher` and process one file at a time as first in first out processing of files in C#.

Comment: What is the type of your application, WinForms? Also what .NET platform are you targeting? .NET 7? .NET Framework?

Comment: The file system watcher produces events, one at a time. Create an event handler and you will see them in the order in which they come. What problem(s) are you seeing in your code (which you should post with your question). It's worth noting that some file system operations produce 2 consecutive events, so you need to accommodate that possibility

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Flydog57 the `FileSystemWatcher` generally fires the events on the `ThreadPool`, so overlapping event invocations are possible. Unless the [`SynchronizingObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobject) has been initialized to the `Form`, in which case the events are raised on the UI thread (sequentially). I guess that the OP would prefer to do the processing on background thread(s), to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: Initialize a working Thread that reads from a [Channel<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1), when something is available. `T` can be a class object that contains the needed details (or just a simple string if nothing else is needed). The FSW event(s) just write to it (as you're correctly assuming, you cannot process anything in those handlers, you have to offload any work) -- Double the size of the default buffer of your FSW

Comment: are you sure files are even copied in an ordered manner? Modern filesystem operations are asynchronous so multiple files may be copied at the same time

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, its not a winform just to watch over a directory i have used filesystemwatcher and when multiple files are copied over there the small file will be copied first and moved for processing. I do not want to do that i want FIFO processing over there, i am using .net framework

Comment: Yes, but what is the type of the application? WPF? ASP.NET? Console application? Knowing the application type might help us give you more targeted answers. You can edit the question and provide any additional information there.

Comment: I would say that only a filesystem filter with synchronous reporting (i.e., each operation is reported right when it is performed) would do the job. CBFS Filter [I am related to it], is one of the options, and there exist others.